# String/vector concatenation symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, math-operators, vector

I'm looking for a math symbol to represent the concatenation of two vectors: if ***x*** = (*x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>) and ***y*** = (*y*<sub>1</sub>, *y*<sub>2</sub>) then ***x*** ? ***y*** = (*x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>, *y*<sub>1</sub>, *y*<sub>2</sub>).

I'm not very much at home in vector calculus, so I don't know if there's a standard symbol for this. If not, then I remember from formal language theory that there's a round caret-like symbol for concatenating two strings, which would be fine for my purposes. I can't find it, though; the sources I've found online all recommend using juxtaposition for concatenation, but I'm afraid this would be mistaken for the dot product.

I'm using `elsarticle.cls`, so `amsmath` and `amssymb` are both available.

Comment: I math it is often written as (x,y), with an implicit identification of ℝ²×ℝ² and ℝ^4.

Comment: Ben seems to already have done that. Harold's suggestion is also common, using (more or less) the same identification.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298648/is-there-a-common-symbol-for-concatenating-two-finite-sequences) is the same question on Math SE.

Comment: `\frown`! That's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a vector in R^2 is written (1, 2), it would make sense to concatenate two vectors a and b as (a,b).

Comment: This is also how it's done in some programming languages, e.g. Matlab.

Answer (score 11):

Personally, I would use `\oplus` for this. I would think of it as a direct sum of two vectors (as a member of the direct sum of two vector spaces).

Comment: Plus you can use `\bigoplus` to easily represent the concatenation of multiple vectors!

Comment: This notation doesn't really work that well for tensors, since they must be concatenated along only one axis (which is not specified by this notation).

Answer (score 6):

You can use two pluses joined together, which is rather intuitive

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\concat}{\ensuremath{+\!\!\!\!+\,}}
\begin{document}
$a \concat b$
\end{document}
```

Another symbol is ||

```
 \[ p\|q=p b^{l(q)}+q \]
```

The `\|` command gives a double vertical bar.

Answer (score 1):

Computer science often uses the ⧺ (U+29FA) symbol. (String concatenation is `++` in the Haskell programming language, to represent this.)

This is `\doubleplus` in `unicode-math` and the legacy packages `stix` and `stix2`.  Or, in the modern toolchain, you can use the Unicode symbol in your source.