# How do I typeset the concatenation of strings properly?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am looking for a good way to typeset the concatenation of two strings. This is standard notation in descriptive set theory to join an m-tuple `x` to an n-tuple `y` to get an (m+n)-tuple `x^y`, that is, a small slightly raised circumflex or frown joining the upper parts of the characters together. I currently use the straightforward

```
x^\smallfrown y
```

which doesn't look terribly good.

Semantically, this is a binary operation, but it shouldn't have the usual spacing on the right and the left and it should be higher up than a minus sign, say.

Here's a sample screen shot from Moschovakis's *[Descriptive set theory](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ynm/lectures/dst2009/)* (p.76 of the pdf) which is approximately what I'd like to do, but I'd prefer a frown:

[image: Sample screen shot from Moschovakis]

---

Looking around on this site, I found the question [String/vector concatenation symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8397) but it is concerned with *which* symbol to use for the operation, so it doesn't address my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define a binary math command (`\mathbin`) that is typeset according to your specifications:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\concatA}{%
  \mathbin{\raisebox{1ex}{\scalebox{.7}{$\frown$}}}%
}
\newcommand{\concatB}{%
  \mathbin{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\scalebox{.7}{(\kern1ex)}}}
}
\begin{document}
$x\concatA y\ x\concatB y$
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

`\concatA` could be what you're after, although I've also added `\concatB` to show you another possibility. There may be more, so if you're interested, see [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764).

You can fiddle around with the `\frown` raise (`1ex`) as well as the size (scaled to `.7` of its original size thanks to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)).

It sounds logical to me to have the spacing set as `\mathbin` since it represents an operator acting on two entities (operands). However, you can use `\mathord` to remove the binary-operator-ness. Perhaps even specifying your own spacing around the symbol with additional `\mkern`s if needed.

Comment: The original post asked to remove the spaces around the operator. So it would be better to use `\mathord` instead of `\mathbin`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the quick response (and the edit to my question). Yes, `\concatA` is essentially what I want, except for the spacing around the operation which is taken care of by @Guido's comment. I'll leave this open for a few hours to see if someone else has another suggestion but in my document it works the way I wanted.

Comment: @Guido: True. I've referenced that in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: There is one problem with the suggested solution: I often need the command in subscripts, e.g. `N_{x \concatA y}` and your solution doesn't seem to scale properly, like the ordinary operations like `+` do. How do I get it to do that?

Comment: @geezer: That wasn't part of the original request. However, without repeating Guido's suggestion, see his answer for an alternative that provides this functionality.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it wasn't. I don't know much about the inner workings of LaTeX, so I didn't expect this to be a problem. Thanks again for your help, the additional links and explanations were really helpful! With Guido's addition everything seems to work the way I expected it to.

Answer (score 5):

You can expand on Werner's solution using `\mathchoice`.

```
\newcommand{\concatA}{%
  \mathord{
    \mathchoice
    {\raisebox{1ex}{\scalebox{.7}{$\frown$}}}
    {\raisebox{1ex}{\scalebox{.7}{$\frown$}}}
    {\raisebox{.7ex}{\scalebox{.5}{$\frown$}}}
    {\raisebox{.7ex}{\scalebox{.5}{$\frown$}}}
  }
}
```

Comment: That led to exactly the solution I needed. Thanks a lot!